# Mediaelement loads video player in an audio tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, mediaelement.js

I'm using a javascript code to load links to mp3 using medialement.js

The configuration is as follows:

HTML

```
<a class="audio-player" href="some.mp3">This mp3 is cool</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var audioDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-player");
$(audioDiv).each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).className != 'mediaplayer-processed') {
    var playlist = $(this).attr('href');
    playlist = playlist.replace("%20", " ");
    sourceType = playlist.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if (sourceType == 'mp3') {
      sourceType = 'mpeg';
    }
    audioTag = '<audio class="audio-player">'
    audioTag = audioTag + '<source type="audio/' + sourceType + '" src="' + playlist + '" />';
    audioTag = audioTag + '</audio>';
    $(this).outerHTML=audioTag;
    config_me = {
      // enables Flash and Silverlight to resize to content size
      enableAutosize: true,
      // the order of controls you want on the control bar (and other plugins below)
      features: ['playpause','volume'],
      // Hide controls when playing and mouse is not over the video
      alwaysShowControls: true,
    };
    // I need to set the video height and width because it is displayed as video
    config_me.videoHeight = 30;
    config_me.videoWidth = 60;
    config_me.audioWidth = 60;
    config_me.audioHeight = 30;
    config_me.loop = false;

    $(this).addClass('mediaplayer-processed').mediaelementplayer(config_me);
  }
});
```

Now what I would expect/want is a minimalistic audio player, but what I get is a full video player and mediaelement loads with the class "mejs-video" instead "mejs-audio".

I tried forcing the type in config_me, but it is still loaded as a video.

Am I missing something? I'm using mediaelement 2.15.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some subtle details you should consider in your code

**FIRST**, this :

```
$(this).outerHTML = audioTag;
```

... will never work (see **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsw8t2dg/)**) because `$(this)` refers to a jQuery *object*, not to a document *object*.

Because of that, the `<audio>` tag never replaces the `<a>` tag, so

```
$(this).addClass('mediaplayer-processed').mediaelementplayer(config_me);
```

... is actually binding `mediaelementplayer()` to your current `<a>` tag, and MEJS configures it as `video` by default because there is nothing in there that tells it's an audio.

In that case, you should do :

```
this.outerHTML = audioTag;
```

See **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsw8t2dg/1/)**

---

**SECOND**, after you finally replace the `a` tag with the `video` tag, this

```
$(this).addClass('mediaplayer-processed').mediaelementplayer(config_me);
```

... still doesn't bind `mediaelementplayer()` to the `audio` tag because `$(this)` refers to an element that doesn't exist anymore (the `<a>` tag) so in that case you should do :

```
$(".audio-player").addClass('mediaplayer-processed').mediaelementplayer(config_me);
```

... because the `video` tag now also shares the `audio-player` *class*.

Please **notice** however, that if you initialize `mediaelementplayer()` inside the `.each()` method, only the first element will be correctly initialized because it will be the only one `audio` tag with that *class*. The rest of the elements with *class* `audio-player` are still `<a>` tags during the first loop (and you will be back to your original problem)

As a workaround, you have two options :

1. Leave the `mediaelementplayer()` method inside the `.each()` method BUT add different classes to your new `video` tags like :

   ```
   audioTag = '<audio class="audio-player'+index+'">'
   ```

   ... then, initialize them like :

   ```
   $(".audio-player"+index+"").addClass('mediaplayer-processed').mediaelementplayer(config_me);
   ```
2. Leave your code the way it is but just move the `mediaelementplayer()` method after the `.each()` method like :

   ```
   $(audioDiv).each(function (index) { 
       if() {... }
   });
   $(".audio-player").addClass('mediaplayer-processed').mediaelementplayer(config_me);
   ```

**NOTICE** either of the configurations above will convert ALL `a` tags into `audio` tags on page load.

Here is your complete working code with the second option

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var audioDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-player");
    $(audioDiv).each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).className != 'mediaplayer-processed') {
            var playlist = $(this).attr('href');
            playlist = playlist.replace("%20", " ");
            sourceType = playlist.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            console.log(sourceType);
            if (sourceType == 'mp3') {
                sourceType = 'mpeg';
            }
            audioTag = '<audio class="audio-player">'
            audioTag = audioTag + '<source type="audio/' + sourceType + '" src="' + playlist + '" />';
            audioTag = audioTag + '</audio>';
            // $(this).outerHTML = audioTag;
            this.outerHTML = audioTag;
            config_me = {
                enableAutosize: true,
                features: ['playpause', 'volume'],
                alwaysShowControls: true,
            };
            //config_me.videoHeight = 30;
            //config_me.videoWidth = 60;
            config_me.audioWidth = 120;
            config_me.audioHeight = 30;
            config_me.loop = false;
        }
    }); // each
    $(".audio-player").addClass('mediaplayer-processed').mediaelementplayer(config_me);
}); // ready
```

See **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3jwvmdg/)**

**Notice** I set a higher `width` in `config_me.audioWidth = 120;` because you will need some extra room for the volume handler.

---

**THIRD**, if your idea is that `audio` elements should be shown after clicking the corresponding link (and not on page load as in the example above), then you have to bind a `click` event using the `.on()` method **inside** the `.each()` method.

**Notice** that in this case, it's advisable to add a different *class* to each `audio` tag (as in option 1 above) so we can initialize them individually after each `click` so

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var audioDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-player");
    $(audioDiv).each(function (index) {
        $(this).on("click", function (e) {
            if ($(this).className != 'mediaplayer-processed') {
                var playlist = this.href; // $(this).attr('href');
                playlist = playlist.replace("%20", " ");
                sourceType = playlist.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
                console.log(sourceType);
                if (sourceType == 'mp3') {
                    sourceType = 'mpeg';
                }
                audioTag = '<audio class="audio-player'+index+'">'
                audioTag = audioTag + '<source type="audio/' + sourceType + '" src="' + playlist + '" />';
                audioTag = audioTag + '</audio>';
                // $(this).outerHTML = audioTag;
                this.outerHTML = audioTag;
                config_me = {
                    enableAutosize: true,
                    features: ['playpause', 'volume'],
                    alwaysShowControls: true,
                };
                //config_me.videoHeight = 30;
                //config_me.videoWidth = 60;
                config_me.audioWidth = 120;
                config_me.audioHeight = 30;
                config_me.loop = false;
                $(".audio-player"+index+"").addClass('mediaplayer-processed').mediaelementplayer(config_me);
            }
            return false;
       }); // on
    }); // each
}); // ready
```

See **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2o0dx2t/1/)**

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail answer! I got it working perfectly now, and most important, I learned a bit more about JS.