# How to generate audio shortcode when there's an mp3 in a link tag in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, audio

I'm trying to write a function that will overwrite any `<a>` tag with a .mp3 URL with the Wordpress audio shortcode.

I'm pulling posts into Wordpress from an api — so I can't manually add the audio shortcode to mp3 links in each post — or even have the mp3 URL on its own line, which would automatically generate the shortcode. The posts are radio stories. Each begins with an `<a>` tag structured exactly like this:

```
<a href="https:storyurl.mp3" class="asset-audio">Hear the radio version of this story.</a>
```

And I believe this is what I need to convert that tag into:

```
[audio mp3="https:storyurl.mp3" class="asset-audio" title="Hear the radio version of this story."]
```

There are audio player plugins that will recognize any mp3 and wrap it in its own shortcode, but Wordpress doesn't do this by default with its core mediaelement.js. I hope to accomplish that in my child theme's functions.php.

Comment: I think your best bet is going to be looking at the post content (maybe hooking into `the_content` filter), and using regular expressions to find the information. Are you familiar with `preg_match_all()` and `preg_replace()`?

Comment: I wasn't familiar but just googled. That does make sense. Basically, a find and replace. I hadn't thought of attacking it that way. I'm assuming there is some way to write the ```preg_match_all``` logic with a sort of "wild card" in part of the criteria. The match criteria must include ```.mp3``` but not the rest of the URL. Anyway, I'll fiddle with that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, Regex (Regular Expressions) are pretty powerful. Here's how I'd do the replace:

```
$reg = "#<a [^>]*href=['\"]([^\"']+\.mp3)['\"][^>]*>(.*?)</a>#";
$content = preg_replace($reg, "[audio mp3='$1' class='asset-audio' title='$2']", $content);
```

Where `$content` is whatever variable that holds the content of the post. I'll explain what the regex is doing:

"#" - The first and last characters are delimiters. They're not actually part of the match

"<a " - The start of a link tag

"[^>]*" - the [] means it's looking for any of a group of characters. The ^ is a negator, meaning "NOT." The "*" means 0 or more of these characters. Altogether it means "Look for 0 or more of any character accept ">", which keeps us inside the "a" tag.

"href=" - just to find that text

"['\"]" - The opening quotation mark

"([^\"']+.mp3)" - The parenthesis lets us access this string later (in the replace part). the bracketed part means we're looningh for any character accept the closing quote (since neither quote characters usually show up in a link, we're mostly safe doing this). The "+" means it's looking for 1 or more of these characters. The . means a literal period chacacter, and mp3 (so we only match mp3 links!)

"['\"]" - The closing quote

"[^>]*>" - Any number of non-">" characters, followed by >

"(.*?)" - Parenthesis again to capture this string. The "." means any character, the * means 0 or more, and the "?" means to not be aggressive... as in to match as few characters as possible (otherwise it will keep going until the closing tag of the last link in the post

"</a" - to make sure we get all the way to the closing tag

In the replacement part, notice $1 and $2. Those refer to the first and second parenthesis in the match.

This is not a complete explanation of all that's going on with regex, and it's not a 100% perfect solution, but it should work in your case at almost 100%. Regex is practically a language unto itself and there's a lot to research there. I encourage you to learn it and get good at it, because there are a lot of uses for it!

I also didn't answer the rest of your question, namely how to intercept and change the post content on its way from the database to the screen. If you need help on that side, too, let me know.

EDIT------------------------

Here's how I'd do it in a plugin or functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'myprefix_use_audio_short_tag' );

function myprefix_use_audio_short_tag( $content ) {
    $reg = "#<a [^>]*href=['\"]([^\"']+\.mp3)['\"][^>]*>(.*?)</a#";
    $content = preg_replace($reg, "[audio mp3='$1' class='asset-audio' title='$2']", $content);

    return $content;
}
```

The "Add Filter" function with "the_content" as the filter adds your function to the queue of functions that have to run against the post content every time it's accessed from the database. This should have your desired result.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for taking the time to answer this so clearly! I did go down the regex rabbit hole a bit. Fascinating. I get how powerful it can be - even if it makes my eyes cross a little bit at this point.  

In reference to your last paragraph: I'm glad you phrased it that way. What I don't want to do is run a script on the database to change all of these links there. I want to do exactly what you say: "intercept and change the post content on its way from the database to the screen." I would love to know how you recommend handling that.

Comment: I did come across a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470658/mediaelement-loads-video-player-in-an-audio-tag

Comment: That method for configuring mediaelement.js (described in the link I just posted) does work — sort of. But I'm running into another issue - since I'm using AJAX to load the page, the script isn't reloading with each AJAX call.. and I know there are workarounds for that. I have a feeling your solution is simpler.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not much with javascript. I've been reading up on it, but I'm way stronger in PHP. This method seems more reliable to me, but that could be my bias. I updated my answer to include how you might use a filter (specifically 'the_content') to do what you want. If you find `the_content` is too broad and affects too many items, there are a zillion filters in WP that might help. You'll have to do some searching if you want to try a different filter.

Comment: And I didn't test this code. It's possible that this happens after the shortcodes are processed. If so, just change the last line of the function to `return do_shortcode( $content );`

Comment: This is working so much better than what I was doing with Javascript, and I'm able to drastically reduce the amount of code — it's handling the AJAX calls fine, with no need to reload a script. Thank you so much @Stevish! The only tiny tweak was that the regex string needed a closing ```>``` at the end of closing ```</a``` tag. Otherwise, it doesn't replace that and leaves a ```>``` rendered as text after the player. Anyway, I owe ya one!

Comment: Thanks, @MLine! I've updated the answer. I was still thinking of just the match when I decided to leave off the trailing `>`, and didn't consider the replacement. Thanks for commenting to make this answer more complete!

Answer (score 0):

Paste the code in your javascript file and it will solve your issue. I hope so.

```
$('.asset-audio').each(function(){
   var newtag = "[audio mp3="+ $(this).attr('href') +" class="+ 
   $(this).attr('class') +" title="+ $(this).html() +"]";
   $(this).after(newtag);
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Suresh! When you say "in your javascript file," which file are you referring to? I guess my thought is - create an external javascript file, and use wp_enqueue_scripts in functions.php to import it.

Comment: Yes, you can create the external file and also you can add this code with wp_head action hook.